# How to hide name of tab in taskbar Chrome / Brave

Tags: windows, google-chrome, taskbar, brave

Due to privacy, I want to hide the tab name in the Windows taskbar.
Now it appears like this:
[image: Windows Taskbar]

I want it to say just "Google Chrome", not also Youtube.

Is there a way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab title is just whatever is defined by the webpage it contains.

For automatically renaming webpages, you could use the extension
[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en)
with a userscript such as
[Rename Tab](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/161135),
which is replicated here with your title:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Rename Tab
// @namespace   http://.userscripts-mirror.org/
// @include http://www.netvibes.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

window.addEventListener ("load", Greasemonkey_main, false);

function Greasemonkey_main () {

        (function() {document.title="Google Chrome";})();
        
}
```

For manually renaming a page, you may use these methods :

- The extension
  [Simple Tab Renamer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/simple-tab-renamer/ailhpmlejogfdcpoflidmobgkgdemaog?hl=en)
- Pinning a tab will hide its name
- Grouping tabs will hide their titles
- The Javascript console with the
  [code](https://dev.to/barakplasma/rename-tabs-without-an-extension-4nc0)
  `document.title = "YOUR_NEW_TAB_TITLE";`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't want to change tab title. I want to remove tab title from the title of opened application in Windows.

Comment: As far as I know, there is only one title and you can't disassociate the tab from the taskbar.